# How to make this CLR work with 2005?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005, clr, sqlclr

I am trying to make a clr stored procedure for a sql 2005 database that uses .net 3.5 assemblies

So first I had to change sql 2005 to recognize system.core as unsafe what I am not too happy about(I rather have had it say SAFE).

Now I get this error

```
 Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Procedure StoredProcedure1, Line 0
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user defined routine or aggregate 'StoredProcedure1': 
System.Security.HostProtectionException: Attempted to perform an operation that was forbidden by the CLR host.

The protected resources (only available with full trust) were: All
The demanded resources were: MayLeakOnAbort

System.Security.HostProtectionException: 
   at StoredProcedures.StoredProcedure1(String UtcDateTime)
```

Here is my code

```
Exec StoredProcedure1 '7/8/2010 5:00:00 am'


using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;


public partial class StoredProcedures
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
    public static void StoredProcedure1(string UtcDateTime)
    {
        SqlPipe p = SqlContext.Pipe;
        DateTime converted = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(Convert.ToDateTime(UtcDateTime), "Pacific Standard Time");

        p.Send(converted.ToString());

    }
};
```

I did not know how to pass in a datetime into it so I used a string then converted it.

Comment: You cannot use TimeZoneInfo.  Period.  Do not pass Go, do not collect $200.

Comment: Ok......Some alternatives would be nice a reason maybe why too might nice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get this to work you'd have to set it as UNSAFE.

Apparently, some TimeZoneInfo methods have [HostProtectionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403276.aspx) set which means they can't be used in SQL Server CLR code.

Unless you decide "I don't care about stability and know better". I take no responsibility if your server becomes a smoking crater in the ground if you use UNSAFE...