# sql server convert datetime into another timezone?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How do I convert the current time (datetime) in my timezone into another timezone, say France ? I looked around in SO, but did not find any posts which could help me. I am using SQL server 2008.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872007/date-time-conversion-from-timezone-to-timezone-in-sql-server

Comment: @fan711 - okay, i'll check that and see how it goes. btw, its a sql server 2012 question.

Comment: Do you have your current Datetime column datatype as Datetimeoffset ??or is it just Datetime ??

Comment: @MuhammedAli - only datetime.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 select CONVERT(datetime,SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(datetimeoffset,GetUTCDate()),'+05:30')) Date_India,

 select CONVERT(datetime,SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(datetimeoffset,GetUTCDate()),'+03:30')) Date_Iran
```

[check here](http://mssqlfun.com/2012/07/26/how-to-insert-datetime-with-different-timezones/)

Comment: Thanks, but i get the error 'SWITCHOFFSET' is not a recognized built-in function name. on ss2000 and ss2005.

Comment: query says indian time = 2013-10-30 18:59:51.060. google says 2AM oct 31.

Comment: Please change getdate() to **GetUTCDate()**

Answer (score 2):

Please replace getdate() with GetUTCDate() to get accurate result otherwise the offset (5:30) in this case will be added to the current time (which will already have some offset) and will result in incorrect result.

For instance if you are in Pakistan then GetDate() will give you time as GMT+5:00 and adding 5:50 offset in this time will result in GMT + 10:30 which is totally wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I also agree the correct SQL Query is using `GetUTCDate()` as you see in the screenshot.

```
select CONVERT(datetime,SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(datetimeoffset,GetUTCDate()),'+05:30')) Date_India_withUtcDate
```

[image]