# Incorrect time entry in datetime sql server format

Tags: c#, date, datetime

Hi the query below performs an insert on sql server, when the insert is done date minutes and seconds are correct but the time is wrong (if there are 8 and I insert an insert the value is saved 7) the format of the hours is that Italian, below the sql code that executes the insert. How do I solve this?

**Sql Server:**

```
Insert into Magazzino(Nome,Indirizzo,DataCreazione) 
values(@Nome,@Indirizzo,convert(datetime, GETDATE(),105))
```

Comment: What is the type of `DataCreazione` column? This sounds like a representation issue. `datetime` itself does not have any format.

Comment: is datetime....

Comment: Have you got the right Time Region? At the command line do a `tzutil /g`

Comment: What is the point of converting the date to insert it into the database?

Comment: @Petaflop convert date to italian format

Comment: @riki Huh? Is `GETDATE()` actually a Italian date string you're inserting?

Comment: @JeremyThompson W. Europe Standard Time

Comment: 105 format is "dd-mm-yyyy". You can store without converting it and convert it while displaying on UI. No meaning of converting it while storing.

Comment: `datetime2` (and it's related similar types) don't **have** a format. They're a count of the number of intervals that have occurred since some epoch date. Leave **formatting** to your presentation layer - not the database.

Comment: @GaurangDave - the *style* parameter to convert is going to be ignored. `GETDATE()` returns a `datetime`. The `CONVERT` call is being asked to convert its input to a `datetime`. That's a no-op - it just returns its input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) states that `GETDATE()` stores the date and time **of the computer** on which the instance of SQL server is running. To resolve this, you have two options:

- Update configuration of SQL server instance. See [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverfaq/2009/11/13/how-to-change-date-format-after-installing-sql-server/) - this may require Operations/MIS support.
- Use `datetimeoffset` on `GetUTCDate()`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19613638/sql-server-convert-datetime-into-another-timezone).

P.S.: Kindly change the tag of this question to *t-sql* or *sql-server*!