# How to convert UTC TIme to countries time using Offset with daylight saving in SQL server?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, timezone, dst

In our organization, we are planning to store different countries data in a single sql server.

So that we are planning to manipulate datetime with their countries Offset.

Is that only enough? Else we have to consider daylight saving time for this manipulation?

When daylight savings occur, the server (where sql server installed)  time will be changed?? (How it can be achieved?)

Comment: Starting with version 2008 there are new date/time types: Read about [datetimeoffset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx). On this page there are links to other types, you might read about `datetime2` too.

Comment: No, storing an offset is not enough.  Read "time zone != offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), and see [this dup post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872007/date-time-conversion-from-timezone-to-timezone-in-sql-server) for SQL specific advice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Date time conversion from timezone to timezone in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872007/date-time-conversion-from-timezone-to-timezone-in-sql-server)