# How to convert date from Germany to local date in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a column in a table with time stamps from Germany (Utc + 6)  in their local time (Utc -1). How do I convert all those datetimes in my local time?

Comment: What is your dbms?

Comment: what version of sql?

Comment: This post shows no research or effort on your part. What have you looked up, tried to implement, and found to not work?

Comment: sequel server 2014

Comment: What is your local culture info?

Comment: Central time zone US

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the correct way of converting UTC datetime into local datetime is using CLR function. You can find an example below.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2339/converting-utc-to-local-time-with-sql-server-clr/

Answer (score 1):

There are -7 hour between germany and central time zone in us

```
CT (-6)
Berlin (+1)
```

If your column is datetime USE THE FOLLOWING

```
Select DATEADD(HOUR,-7,[DATECOLUMN])
```

**Update 1**

Consider that @bdate and @edate are the begin and end date of the daylight savings so you can use this query

```
Select case when DATEADD(HOUR,-7,[DATECOLUMN]) between @bdate and @edate Then
DATEADD(HOUR,-8,[DATECOLUMN])  else 
DATEADD(HOUR,-7,[DATECOLUMN]) end
```

Comment: It won't work because of day light savings in the US... when we change the clock I would have to adjust the code

Comment: Day light saving is not a fixed period it changes every year. !!

Comment: Germany doesn't have day light savings though. It is 8:30 pm in Germany now and 1:30 pm in the US. When the US changes its clock one hour backward, it will be 12:30 pm in the US and still 8:30 pm in Germany.

Comment: @ValK That s mean that your destination date time has daylight savings not the timestamp in ur data. So you are the one that must set that option.

Comment: @ValK: Germany **does** have daylight savings time (just not now in February)

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in a string format like "dd.mm.yy," then you would use the code page 104 to tell SQL how to parse your date from string to a DateTime format.

```
CONVERT(DateTime, DateField, 104)
```

If your string is in some other format, then look up the correct codepage in the table [here (CAST and CONVERT in T-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=sql.90%29.aspx):

Comment: the link is broken

Comment: [Datetime Conversion from Timezone to Timezone in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872007/date-time-conversion-from-timezone-to-timezone-in-sql-server)