# GMT to EST Time zone conversion SSIS/SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Do we have any method in SSIS or SQL Server 2016 by which I can convert GMT to EST time zone.

Case is as follow.

I have a database having datetime column [EventDateTime] which is in GMT Time zone.

What I am doing here is, using SSIS and loading this data into SQL server. Is there a way I can convert GMT timezone to EST timezone while doing SSIS

OR

If there is a way if I can convert GMT to EST after loading into SQL Server.

> ***Note: Please consider Day Light Saving time as well. Day Light Saving Condition: Between Second Sunday of March @ 7:00AM GMT to First
>   Sunday of November @6:00AM GMT time difference is 4Hrs else its
>   5Hrs***

---

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Date time conversion from timezone to timezone in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872007/date-time-conversion-from-timezone-to-timezone-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following link addresses your question and takes into account Day Light Savings Time.  It provides a workaround to this limitation in SQL Server.

[Date time conversion from timezone to timezone in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872007/date-time-conversion-from-timezone-to-timezone-in-sql-server)

You could apply this approach in an Execute SQL Task and return the result to a variable for use in other control/data flow tasks.

Hope this helps.