# to compare Indian time

Tags: c#, sql-server, comparison, timezone

I want to find out what will be the time in india when clock tick to 1Am mid night in any other country..
How i will find out that through any means
plz help me to find out this 
this is to fire birthbay mails at 1AM midnight of that resp country...

Comment: Possible dupe question(s): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200827/how-to-convert-timezones-in-sql-server-2005 , etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SQL SERVER 2008 would have the DATETIMEOFFSET data type (which includes the time zone) plus functions like SWITCHOFFSET to switch from one timezone offset to another.

What version are you on?

Answer (score 1):

.NET 3.5 added the class [TimeZoneInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx) which should be able to do want you want. Particularly, the [TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime, TimeZoneInfo, TimeZoneInfo)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382770.aspx) method.

You can also use the [TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.getsystemtimezones.aspx) method to get the list of time zones that are registered in the system.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the method:

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime
```